# sum of converted values in columns in ssrs 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I need help trying to get sum of columns using ssrs 2005 
but my values are converted from the answer to be a number 
so if the answer was very, it would be converted to a 3, and if answer was quite, it would be converted to a 2. 
but then i need to get the total of that column of those numbers 
so my table columns would have this [image]

and the expresion in survey column has this

```
=iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Very",CInt(3),iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Quite",CInt(2),iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Slightly",CInt(1),iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Not at all" ,CInt(0),""))))
```

and this is what im trying to achieve the total of survey

```
Food dish           type    survey

Italian soup        A       3

Pizza Supreme       B       2

Pizza Supreme       B       2

Spaghetti           C       1

Total                       8
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you name the textbox "SurveyResult", then do `SUM(ReportItems!SurveyResult.Value)` in the total line?

Comment: hello Daniel i get an error saying 
The Value expression for the textbox 'Textbox3' uses an aggregate function on a report item.  Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers. Which this is placed in the footer of the table

Comment: I was afraid of that, what about `SUM(put your iif statement here)`

Comment: Also you might want to look at `SWITCH` statements to replace that iif, it would be much easier to read.

Comment: i tried that sum with the if statement and it gave an error :( ill look at that switch

Comment: The better way to do it is to make that conversion in the result set and then you will have a normal integer field to sum up...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace the ? in your = Sum ( ? ) expression with the entire Iif function from your detail row, e.g.

`= Sum ( iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Very",CInt(3),iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Quite",CInt(2),iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Slightly",CInt(1),iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Not at all" ,CInt(0),"")))) )`

Comment: Hello Mike thanks for your reply but i get an error The Value expression for the textbox ‘Textbox3’ uses a numeric aggregate function on data that is not numeric.  Numeric aggregate functions (Sum, Avg, StDev, Var, StDevP, and VarP) can only aggregate numeric data.

Comment: I think this is caused by your final `""` - try replacing that with `CInt(0)`

Comment: this worked = Sum ( iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Very",CInt(3),iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Quite",CInt(2),iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Slightly",CInt(1),iif(Fields!Answer4.Value="Not at all" ,CInt(0),CInt(0))))) )